# Replacing values from list of custom objects with map values

Tags: scala

I have a quite odd problem to solve, I have a String, a custom Type and a Map of Maps.

The string needs to have a few values replaced based on mapping between a value in custom type (which is a key in the map of maps).

This is the current structure:

```
case class Students(favSubject: String)

val mapping: Map[String, Map[String, String]] = Map("John" -> Map("English" -> "Soccer"))

val studentInfo: List[Students] = List(Students("English"))

val data: String = "John is the favourite hobby"
```

I tried the following:

```
mapping.foldLeft(data){ case (outputString, (studentName, favSubject)) => outputString.replace(studentName, favSubject.getOrElse(studentInfo.map(x => x.favSubject).toString, "")) }
```

What I need to get is:

```
"Soccer is the favourite hobby"
```

What I get is:

```
"  is the favourite hobby"
```

So looks like I am getting the map of maps traversal right but the getOrElse part is having issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you map() a List, you get a List back. It's toString has a format `"List(el1,el2,...)"`. Surely you cannot use it as a key for your sub-map, you would want just `el1`.

Here is a version of the working code. It might not be a solution you are looking for(!), just a solution to your question:

```
case class Students(favSubject: String)

val mapping: Map[String, Map[String, String]] = Map("John" -> Map("English" -> "Soccer"))
val studentInfo: List[Students] = List(Students("English"))
val data: String = "John is the favourite hobby"

val res = mapping.foldLeft(data) {
      case (outputString, (studentName, favSubjectDict)) => 
           outputString.replace(
              studentName, 
              favSubjectDict.getOrElse(studentInfo.map(x => x.favSubject).head, "?")
           ) 
}
println(s"$res") //prints "Soccer is the favourite hobby"

val notMatchingSubject = studentInfo.map(x => x.favSubject).toString
println(s"Problem in previous code: '$notMatchingSubject' !== 'English'")
```

Try it here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/flQNRrUQSXWPxSTXOPPFgA

**The issue**

It is a bit unclear why StudentInfo is a List in this form... If I guessed, it was designed to be a list of StudentInfo containing both, name and favSubject and you would need to search it by name to find favSubject. But it is just a guess.

I went with the simplest working solution, to get a .head (first element) of the sequence from the map. Which will always be "English" even if you add more Studends to the list.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do, would be to first change the structure of **mappings** so it makes more sense for the problem.

```
val mapping: Map[String, Map[String, String]] = Map("John" -> Map("English" -> "Soccer"))

val mapping2 =
  mapping.iterator.flatMap {
    case (student, map) => map.iterator.map {
      case (info, value) => (info, student, value)
    }
  }.toList
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .view
  .mapValues { group =>
    group.iterator.map {
      case (_, student, value) => student -> value
    }.toList
  }.toMap
// mapping2: Map[String, List[(String, String)]] = Map("English" -> List(("John", "Soccer")))
```

Then I would just traverse the students informativo, making all the necessary replacements.

```
final case class StudentInfo(favSubject: String)

val studentsInformation: List[StudentInfo] = List(StudentInfo("English"))

val data: String = "John is the favourite hobby"

val result =
  studentsInformation.foldLeft(data) { (acc, info) =>
    mapping2
      .getOrElse(key = info.favSubject, default = List.empty)
      .foldLeft(acc) { (acc2, tuple) =>
        val (key, replace) = tuple
        acc2.replace(key, replace)
      }
  }
// result: String = "Soccer is the favourite hobby"
```